# Doubt about being muslim

Tags: salat, fiqh

After years of negligence I started to pray and fast.But since few days I am passing wind in wudu and salah.I tried to go toilet but it was for nothing.There is no smell or sound and this condition might change sometime soon until then I don't know whether I am excused because I may get some time without passing wind in Asr.But this is rare.
I am also having extreme doubts about whether there is urine in my clothes.
Due to these reasons I stopped praying  and I  don't know whether my fasts are valid because I don't pray. 
I feel depressed everyday because of this.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum,
Dear brother, i hope allah betters ur condition.

Firstly, if the urine came involuntarily, ur wudu would not be broken, and so salah would be valid.

However, for passing wind, if not 100% sure u did so and u didn't hear/smell anything, ur salah is valid and ur wudu is as well.

Ur doubts may be waswas from shayateen, but remember, shayateen will only hinder those who have belief and so, masha allah, u have belief

Good luck

Comment: What if I am sure?I always feel short amount of gas is always passing in salah

Comment: If u r 100% sure and u heard and smelt it, do wudu again

Comment: Btw, the prophet (saw) had said that wudu is broken when u heard or smelt the gas.